# No B+Tree found in tablespace error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a tablespace from one MySQL server to another.  I was able to successfully discard the namespace and copy the new .ibd file.  However, when I execute the following command -

```
alter table Foo import tablespace;
```

I'm receive the following error -

```
ERROR 1034 (HY000) at line 14: Incorrect key file for table
'Foo'; try to repair it
```

When I review the .err file, I see the real error message -

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: No B+Tree found in tablespace
[Note] InnoDB: Discarding tablespace of table "test"."Foo": Data structure corruption
```

I can't find any references to this error message.  The table contains 0 records.

Comment: Did you create the `.cfg` file? Are you _sure_ they have the _exact same table definition_, which _includes_ keys, not just columns?